# How to write a fomular, that identifies if all tasks within a group are solved,except a certain one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel formula issue. I have plenty of different sized groups. Each group has tasks. I want to check, if all tasks within a group have the status "OK," except one certain task called "change."

The status "change" doesn't matter, but it matters, that I know that the group has the task "change," because there are groups that don't have the task "change." I only want to count the groups that contain the task "change."

In the end, I want to know, if a group has the task "change" or not and if all tasks within the group have all tasks, except "change" in the status OK or NOK.

Please take a look at the picture, for better understanding.

```
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
|  Task   | Status | Group | Result |
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
|         |        | A     |      1 |
| Build   | OK     | A     |        |
| Install | OK     | A     |        |
| Build   | OK     | A     |        |
| Install | OK     | A     |        |
| Build   | OK     | A     |        |
| Install | OK     | A     |        |
| Change  | NOK    | A     |        |
| Change  | NOK    | A     |        |
|         |        | B     |      0 |
| Build   | OK     | B     |        |
| Install | OK     | B     |        |
| Build   | NOK    | B     |        |
| Install | OK     | B     |        |
| Build   | OK     | B     |        |
| Install | OK     | B     |        |
| Change  | NOK    | B     |        |
| Change  | NOK    | B     |        |
|         |        | C     |      1 |
| Build   | OK     | C     |        |
| Install | OK     | C     |        |
| Build   | OK     | C     |        |
| Install | OK     | C     |        |
| Build   | OK     | C     |        |
| Install | OK     | C     |        |
| Change  | OK     | C     |        |
| Change  | OK     | C     |        |
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
```

I tried arrays, index, match, large, min formulas but somehow I don't get the result I want.

Comment: This description is dizzying. Could we just say "Count a group if it has at least one Change task and all other non-change tasks are 'OK'" Is that what you are looking for? I feel that a well crafted '=SumProduct()` would probably do the job here.

Comment: Also check out a table generator website like: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ that allows you to copy and paste from excel and it will make a nice ascii table that can added here as text. It's hard to replicate your table in excel from a picture.

Comment: JNevill, yes, that's how I mean it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your header is starting in A1 and your first formula is in D2, then the following would get you a True/False (1, 0) value for the first group. This works if you copy the cell and paste for the other groups as well:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT((C3:C10=C2)*(A3:A10="Change")*1)>1, SUMPRODUCT((C3:C10=C2)*(B3:B10="OK") * (A3:A10<>"Change")*1)= SUMPRODUCT((C3:C10=C2)* (A3:A10<>"Change")*1))
```

That's a doozie. Basically we are testing two things with an `AND()`:

1. Does the word "Change" exist in column A where the group is in column C.
2. For all cells that don't contain the word "Change" does the count of "OK" tasks (Column B) match the count of all tasks?

If both conditions are true, then you get a `TRUE` value outputted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this looks like I have to do it manually to every group. I have thousand of groups all with different ranges of 2 up to 40 rows. Wouldn't it be necessary to use an array?

Comment: You can change those ranges to cover the entire list and it will still work just fine. Sumproduct pretty much mimics array formulas by it's nature. You'll still be stuck copying and pasting the formula at the top of each group. You could modify the formula wrapping it in an `If(B2="", <big formula here>, "") and copy that down to avoid the work.

Answer (score 0):

We can think this only matters when any non-change task occurs.  Here is my approach:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM($C$3:$C$28)=TRIM(C2)),--(TRIM($A$3:$A$28)<>"Change")*(TRIM($B$3:$B$28)="NOK"))=0,1,0)
```

P.S. I have `TRIM()` here just to make sure there is no leading or trailing empty spaces.